# Apply Discount to Products in Magento Cart page

Tags: magento-1.7

I wanted to know how can I give discount value/percentage on cart page for specific product's quantity dynamically via **OBSERVER**.

Discount can be given on same product's with different quantities.

EX:
*Customer add 4 QTY from Product A and I should be able to give 10% discount on 2 QTYs and the discount value should be shown after subtotal (as normal cart rule applied in Magento)*

If I can create dynamic cart rule and apply that to products which I wanted that also useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total
this is good link to give discount for order , we can modified for particular product & product qty. calculate discount for different product and its qty. add it and setFeeAmount.